# Formato precio, simbolo € a la derecha del precio

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo una aplicación lista en Android Studio pero hay una última cosa que se me a atragantado.
Tengo el símbolo `€` a la izquierda del precio de los artículos que se venden en la App, y como es normal, necesito que aparezca a la derecha de este.

```
€100 = No
100€ = Si
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a resolver esto?

Sus ayudas concretas me ayudarían mucho, por ejemplo, si he de insertar o modificar código que me ayudáseis a saber dónde, en qué archivo, por ejemplo: "Congigs.java", "Strings.xml", etc ya que me estoy volviendo un poco loco.
He revisado muchos foros pero solo veo código que no acabo de lograr insertarlo en ningún sitio.

Answer (score 7):

Realiza una concatenación, toma la variable donde tengas el valor almacenado y concatena el símbolo.
Si tu variable es tipo entero (int) crea otra variable tipo String y concatenas por ejemplo:

```java
int valor=100;
String valorConSimbolo = valor+"€";
```

O en caso de que tu variable es tipo String:

```java
String valorConSimbolo +="€";
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias Antonio por contestar.

Pues he cambiado (dentro de Configs.java):

public static String CURRENCY = "€";

Por la linea que me comentas pero me da error y no funciona. También lo he intentado en "Strings.xml" pero no consigo hacerlo.

Estoy perdidisimo.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

lo que dice el compañero debería funcionar, de todos modos si quieres prueba algo como esto, a ver si así te funciona.

```java
int valor = 5;
char euro = '€';
System.out.println("El valor es " +valor+euro);
```

Comment: Gracias Riancast. Bueno, tampoco funciona pero tampoco sé si lo estoy haciendo bien. He creado un "public static" en Configs.java con el codigo que comentas pero ni siquiera sé si debo pegarlo tal cual me lo has puesto o cambiando "El valor es ". Estoy empezando, muy pez. :(

Comment: No pasa nada Jose, yo también estoy empezando y me cuesta. De todos modos si puedes pegarnos tu código para ver mejor el que está fallando quizás podríamos ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: Has probado a usar la variable estática CURRENCY? es decir, si estás intentando usar esa variable en otra clase, debería ser algo asi como:
System.out.println("El valor es "+valor+class.CURRENCY);
Donde .class sería el nombre de la clase donde está esa variable, de todos modos el system.out.println() se usa en java, en android studio no se muy bien como, ya que no lo he usado mucho, pero deberia ser similar ya que también es java. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Al final ya he encontrado la solución.
Tenía que cambiar **en cada archivo donde aparece el precio** de los productos la linea:

```
priceTV.setText(adObj.getString(Configs.ADS_CURRENCY) + 
String.valueOf(adObj.getNumber(Configs.ADS_PRICE)));
```

Por

```
priceTV.setText("" + String.valueOf(adObj.getNumber(Configs.ADS_PRICE))+ 
adObj.getString(Configs.ADS_CURRENCY));
```

Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas.
Un abrazo